# What is the best method to return JS within a PHP function?

Tags: php, javascript

so I have this PHP function which returns html/js.  But I find the method I am using is wrong and not efficient.  Is there a better way?

Here is just a simplified version of the code.

```
function doSomething() {
$speed = 1000;
$duration = 500;
$start = false; // this is a boolean and doesn't work below (not sure why)

$output = '<div class="container">something</div>' . "\r\n";
$output .= '<script type="text/javascript">' . "\r\n";
$output .= 'jQuery(document).ready(function() {' . "\r\n";
$output .= 'jQuery(".container.").cycle({' . "\r\n";
$output .= 'speed : ' . $speed . ',' . "\r\n";
$output .= 'duration : ' . $duration . ',' . "\r\n";
$output .= 'start : ' . $start . "\r\n"; // this doesn't work I think is because of it becoming a string instead of a boolean here.
$output .= '})' . "\r\n";
$output .= '})' . "\r\n";
$output .= '</script> . "\r\n";
return $output;
}
```

So as you can see above a bunch of output and bunch of linebreaks and basically very hard to maintain and debug.  In addition, the START variable isn't working per the comment.

There has to be a better way.  I thought about heredocs?  But not sure...

Thanks for looking.

Comment: $start doesn't work because it's a boolean, you want to print on a page so it should be $start = 'false'; ie a string

Comment: Have you tried using a PHP template engine..?

Comment: the best way is to to not doing it at all. Exchange data, no code. Keep code separated, keep it decoupled.

Comment: The Idea is to have the JQuery in a textfile(template) with markers that will be replaced with content based on what you pass to it using the PHP template's function.

Comment: the comment above (from @jAndy) should be an answer

Comment: I agree with @jAndy. Why not have a initialization function that fetches all these variables before you initialize all your JQuery..?

Comment: To expand on @DamienPirsy's comment, and to quote [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php): "A boolean TRUE value is converted to the string "1". Boolean FALSE is converted to "" (the empty string)."

Comment: @Rick, just curious as to why this is a requirement..

Comment: Perhaps it was better if I stated the context.  This is a shortcode inside WordPress...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
function doSomething() {        
    $cycleArguments = array(
        'speed'    => 1000,
        'duration' => 500,
        'start'    => false
    );

    $output = '<div class="container">something</div>' . "\r\n";
    $output .= '<script type="text/javascript">' . "\r\n";
    $output .= 'jQuery(document).ready(function() {' . "\r\n";
    $output .= 'jQuery(".container.").cycle(' . "\r\n";
    $output .= json_encode( $cycleArguments );
    $output .= ')' . "\r\n";
    $output .= '})' . "\r\n";
    $output .= '</script>' . "\r\n";
    return $output;
}
```

And with a combination of `json_encode()` *and* heredoc syntax:

```
function doSomething() {        
    $cycleArguments = array(
        'speed'    => 1000,
        'duration' => 500,
        'start'    => false
    );

    $jsonCycleArguments = json_encode( $cycleArguments );

    $output = <<<OUTPUT
    <div class="container">something</div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery(".container.").cycle( $jsonCycleArguments );
    });
    </script>
OUTPUT;
    return $output;
}
```

Another option, still, could be:

```
function doSomething() {        
    $cycleArguments = array(
        'speed'    => 1000,
        'duration' => 500,
        'start'    => false
    );

    $output = array(
        '<div class="container">something</div>',
        '<script type="text/javascript">',
        'jQuery(document).ready(function() {',
        '    jQuery(".container.").cycle(' . json_encode( $cycleArguments ) . ');',
        '});',
        '</script>'
    );

    return implode( "\r\n", $output );
}
```

etc...

Comment: Yes however there is still a bunch of output and linebreaks using this method which I have thought of but just thought there was an even better way.

Comment: @Rick in that case, it might indeed be a better option to use heredoc. And as others have pointed out already; if it's feasible, it's even better to separate HTML code from data structures.

Comment: You need to fix the typo $jsCycleArguments to $jsonCycleArguments

Answer (score 2):

I would use something like the following:

```
function doSomething() {
     $speed = 1000;
     $duration = 500;
     $start = (int)false; // this is a boolean and doesn't work below (not sure why)
     $output = <<<END
       <div class="container">something</div>
       <script type="text/javascript">
         jQuery(document).ready(function() {
         jQuery(".container").cycle({
           speed : $speed ,
           duration : $duration,
           start : $start
          })
        })
       </script>
END;
return $output;
}

echo doSomething();
```

easy to maintain

Comment: @Cthulhu let me do ..for you ..+1 ... and !important was cool ans one

Comment: `END;` must be at the exact beginning of the line though (no whitespace before it), otherwise heredoc won't work.

Comment: fixed it and removed some unnecessary quotes

Answer (score 0):

You can write your code in separate HTML file make AJAX call to that file from php and get code of HTML page in AJAX response use as you want.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of options:

1) at the top of your page (or if you have modularized all JS, and none of it will fire until the bottom of the page, before you call an initialize on anything), have php dump a JSON-encoded multidimensional array, containing all of the data you need on that page, into a single var.

Your JS (stored in static files) will have that var passed into one of the init functions, and will operate on that data.

2) call a php script from the html page `src="script.php"` from there, store the JS as a separate include, either as a HEREDOC or with template values.
Get your values, plug them into the template and echo the string back.
For this to work, you have to mess with MIME types for this to work properly.

3) rewrite your apache installation to rewrite names, write a routing script which will handle the value grabbing and templates, and return a mime type based on the file-extension which was requested.

This is way-overkill for most sites, but is useful for large sites which want all JS to be external, want JS files to contain dynamic data, AND want all script tags to have regular looking `src` tags.

An alternative would be to set php to treat ".js" files like php files (but then you need to figure out the type in the script, to set the MIME type).